# Handling mouse events for tool called by button?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I have a dockable window with a 2 buttons that call 2 different tools (Draw Marker and Select Features), What i want to happen is when the user clicks on the relevant button on the dockable window and then clicks on the map, a onMouseUp event is called and it runs code i need to run.

Where does the onMouseUp event need to be placed so this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not using a dockable window, I do have an addin project where I have a form with buttons on it to draw different shapes on the maps (DrawFeatures). I also have a separate tool (DrawTool) in the project that does all the interaction with the map.

In the DrawFeatures code, the button click subroutine sets the current tool the DrawTool

```
Dim pUID As New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID
Dim pCommandItem As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem

pUID.Value = My.ThisAddIn.IDs.DrawTool
pCommandItem = m_application.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUID, False, False)

m_application.CurrentTool = pCommandItem
```

And here's what the DrawTool code looks like

```
Public Class DrawTool
Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool

'Public LineType As String
Private m_LineFeedback As ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.INewBezierCurveFeedback = Nothing
Private graphicsContainer As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IGraphicsContainer

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal arg As ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseDown(arg)

//code to do all the drawing

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(arg As ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(arg)

    Try
        If m_LineFeedback IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim pPoint As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint = My.ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y)

            m_LineFeedback.AddPoint(pPoint)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```