# On Mouse Up Event in ArcMap Add-In?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, add-in

Does anyone know how to wire up mouse events on a map document?

I have found a bunch of example code on how to wire up Add-In tools, but the Add-in I'm creating is a button.

It should be as easy as wiring up event listeners for ActiveView event listeners, but it seems ESRI takes away the ability of clicking on a map because they want to force us to use tools instead of buttons for map interaction??

Maybe a repost of [Handling mouse events for tool called by button?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75985)

Comment: I've put an example of how I've done that in the linked post.

Comment: The Add-In your using is a Tool, but I'm looking for the ArcMap Mouse Up event listener using a Button Add-In.

Comment: There are no listeners in a Button that will interact with the map. You have to use a Tool. My example shows how to call a Tool from a Button, allowing you to interact with the map.

Comment: Yeah, I went around with ESRI on this. IMO, developers should have access to mouse events on the Map irregardless of what kind of Add-In is being used. This should be the same methodologically as wiring up the IActiveViewEvents.

Answer (score -2):

ESRI prevents developers from having fine grained control over how the user interacts with the map.

So, in order to access a mouse events on the map, a "Tool" Add-In needs to be used.